# How can I differentiate between prediction and intention when I use "will"?

Tags: grammar

> He's sick. **He will see a doctor**

I don't know is it a prediction or intention?
What's the crucial point between prediction and intention when I use "will"?

I need a cut line to differentiate between the two ideas.

Comment: The distinction is in the context, and also native speakers will use a form of words that avoid doubt, e.g. he is planning to see the doctor, or he is expecting to see the doctor.

Comment: This has already been discussed under your earlier question. _He will see a doctor_ suggests that he has an appointment to see one, so I suppose it's a prediction. If it was just an intention you would say _He intends/plans/means to see a doctor_.

Comment: please provide the context!

Answer (score 4):

> He's sick. He will see a doctor

If I heard someone say this, I would presume that "he" didn't wish to see a doctor but that the speaker was mandating it.

**Example**

Roberta: Father, James says he is fine and doesn't need a doctor.

Father: I don't care what he says; He's sick. *He **will** see a doctor*, whether he wants to or not.

---

**EDIT**

As is so often the case, the answer depends on the ***context***. That is why you are getting conflicting answers. You haven't provided context so we have to provide our own.

Comment: what's the priority to mind if there is a lack in context?

Comment: @WaleedGh If no context is supplied, the meaning isn't fully determined. One priority in that case is to ask the speaker what they meant.

Answer (score 4):

One criterion is "Who is making the statement?".

"He will see a doctor." is probably a statement of prediction, because it as a statement about another person.

"I will see a doctor." is probably a statement of the speaker's intention, because it is about oneself. A person usually declares their intentions, rather than making predictions about themselves.

There may be other cases where context indicates the meaning.